# How to serve Yolo 8 captured frames using Pyramid web server

Tags: python, opencv, pyramid, yolov8

I'm a newbie and haven't worked with the Pyramid library/framework before.

I have a script that, based on yolo and supervision, detects, tracks and counts objects. It works great.

Previously, I used streamlit to see the result, but now I need to make a serious application based on this script.

I settled on the fact that I received an annotated frame, and all the logic of the script works.
I have attached a piece of script for understanding

Now I need to open this frame stream in Pyramid.

Please tell me how and where to start? I need a general understanding of the interaction of the existing script with Pyramid; maybe there is an explanatory manual on this topic.

Code examples are not needed - I want to figure it out myself, but the basic steps are very necessary. Thank you

```
def main():
    rtsp_url = "rtsp://"  # Replace with your actual fixed RTSP URL
    cap = VideoCapture(rtsp_url)
    count_object_instance = CountObject(rtsp_url)

    while True:
        frame = cap.read()
        annotated_frame = count_object_instance.process_frame(frame)
        # Do something with the annotated frame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "the pyramid", you might wanna explain that. there's a lot of pyramid schemes in computer vision and deep learning.

Comment: Pyramid - The Start Small, Finish Big, Stay Finished Framework [https://trypyramid.com](https://trypyramid.com)

Comment: ah, a *web framework*. that's beyond me.

Comment: I recommend you provide a [mre]. -- "_Please tell me how and where to start?_" this is kind of out of scope for StackOverflow in my point of view. I guess we can only recommend you to read the documentation and tutorials on the website you linked first before asking your question(s) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyramid is a Python framework for building websites. What you are asking is doable. However, the scope of the question is way too wide to be answerable.

Here is an attempt to answer

- Study how to use Pyramid to run a web server in your application
- Create application with different threads: one for reading media, one for serving HTTP requests
- Have a way of these two threads to communicate with each other e.g. using Python's `Queue` class
- Media thread reads a frame from the video capturing device
- Puts it to the queue
- Pyramid has an API endpoint `image` that reads the latest frame from the queue
- Encodes it as JPEG
- Writes the JPEG data to Pyramid's HTTP `Response` object

[Here is an example of how to embed Pyramid web server in your application](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/trade-executor/tree/master/tradeexecutor/webhook).

[Here is an example of how to encode a live image and serve it from Pyramid's API endpoint](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/trade-executor/blob/17f24a058a9df6b8a289e19c0a47b33b8a39d602/tradeexecutor/webhook/api.py#L272).